# Are all arrays forced to be ByRef when passed into a subroutines?

Tags: vb.net

I just had a quick question to how arrays are passed into subroutines. So I made a subroutine that looked something like this:

```
Sub sortMultiple(ByVal firstArray, ByRef secondArray)
    Array.sort(firstArray, secondArray)
End Sub
```

However it ended up sorting both of the arrays, so I had to end up doing something like this:

```
Sub sortMultiple(ByVal firstArray, ByRef secondArray)
    Dim temp(firstArray.length - 1)
    Array.copy(firstArray, temp, firstArray.length)
    Array.sort(firstArray, secondArray)
End Sub
```

Does this mean that arrays are treated regardless as `ByRef`? And if not, is there a better way of fixing the first example?

Comment: Dupe target doesn't have a marked answer but does explain what you're asking about

Comment: So you want only sort the secondArray?

Comment: They are still ByVal, it's the pointer that is ByVal. You will see the different if you ReDim your array in the method.

Comment: _However it ended up sorting both of the arrays_  That's what it's supposed to do.  See [Array.Sort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3(v=vs.110).aspx): **Each key in the keysArray has a corresponding item in the itemsArray. When a key is repositioned during the sorting, the corresponding item in the itemsArray is similarly repositioned. Therefore, the itemsArray is sorted according to the arrangement of the corresponding keys in the keysArray.** What were you expecting to happen?